# AWS instance accessible by IP only and but not with domain name in Route53

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I really don't know what I am doing wrong and I have searched for solution and all to no avail. My configurations are all okay.

**Scenario**

I have deployed my django app on EC2 ubuntu and I am able to access deployed application on:

- `http://ip-address/en/`
- `http://ip-address:8000/en/`

I can **not** access it on:

- `http://domain/en/`
- `http://domain:8000/en/`

I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error when I access with the domain name.

In Route 53, an A record exists which was set 3 days ago.

When I ping the ip address it returns this:

```
PING ip-address (ip-address) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip-address: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.434 ms
64 bytes from ip-address: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.425 ms
64 bytes from ip-address: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.357 ms
64 bytes from ip-address: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.464 ms
64 bytes from ip-address: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.440 ms
64 bytes from ip-address: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=0.422 ms
64 bytes from ip-address: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=0.420 ms
64 bytes from ip-address: icmp_seq=8 ttl=63 time=0.498 ms
```

When I ping the domain:

```
PING domain.com (ip-address) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ec2-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com (ip-address): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=4.53 ms
64 bytes from ec2-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com (ip-address): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.483 ms
64 bytes from ec2-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com (ip-address): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.385 ms
64 bytes from ec2-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com (ip-address): icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.381 ms
64 bytes from ec2-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com (ip-address): icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.372 ms
```

I have pinged and restarted server several times all to no avail.

Comment: Maybe [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)?